# Clearing the keyboard buffer or blocking input (C# Console)

Tags: c#, console

**"Apologies in advance for the terrible coding" XD**

The problem is that when I switch to a new map, the transition animation starts (darkening and revealing the new map) (in the code, this is NextMap ())
During this animation, I will have time to make a few more moves (let's say to the left), and when the animation ends, my character instantly walks the same number of moves, and I need him to stand near the transition between the maps.
I would like to somehow clear the keyboard buffer when the animation finishes. Is it possible to somehow solve this problem?

*(to better understand my problem, run this code and check my actions)*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace The_Legend_Of_Game
{
    class Program
    {
        public static ConsoleKey key;
        public static string[] map = new string[9];
        public static int[] playerPos = new int[2];
        public static int[] _playerPosTEMP = new int[2];
        public static string mapNow = "10000";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            playerPos[0] /*y*/ = 4;
            playerPos[1] /*x*/ = 7;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                ShowMap(mapNow);

                key = Console.ReadKey(false).Key;
                ControlButtons(key);

            
            }
        }
    
        static void ShowMap(string mapIndex)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            if (mapIndex == "10000")
            {
                map[0] = "███████████████";
                map[1] = "██████████    █";
                map[2] = "██▒██         █";
                map[3] = "█             █";
                map[4] = "              █";
                map[5] = "█             █";
                map[6] = "█             █";
                map[7] = "█             █";
                map[8] = "███████████████";

                ShowMap_();
            }

            if (mapIndex == "11000")
            {
                map[0] = "███████████████";
                map[1] = "█             █";
                map[2] = "█             █";
                map[3] = "█             █";
                map[4] = "               ";
                map[5] = "█             █";
                map[6] = "█             █";
                map[7] = "█             █";
                map[8] = "███████████████";

                ShowMap_();
            }

            if (mapIndex == "12000")
            {
                map[0] = "███████████████";
                map[1] = "█             █";
                map[2] = "█      *      █";
                map[3] = "█             █";
                map[4] = "               ";
                map[5] = "█             █";
                map[6] = "█             █";
                map[7] = "█             █";
                map[8] = "███████████████";

                ShowMap_();
            }
        }

        static void ShowMap_()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                if (playerPos[0] == i)
                {
                    char[] chars = map[i].ToCharArray();
                    chars[playerPos[1]] = '☺';
                    map[i] = new string(chars);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(map[i]);
            }

            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.WriteLine(mapNow);
        }




    


















        static void ControlButtons(ConsoleKey key)
        {
            if (key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
            {
                if (!IsExit(key))
                {
                    if (map[playerPos[0] - 1][playerPos[1]] == '█')
                    {
                        // Nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        playerPos[0]--;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    NextRoom1();



                    NextRoom2();
                }
            }
            if (key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                if (!IsExit(key))
                {
                    if (map[playerPos[0] + 1][playerPos[1]] == '█')
                    {
                        // Nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        playerPos[0]++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    NextRoom1();



                    NextRoom2();
                }
            }
            if (key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
            {
                if (!IsExit(key))
                {
                    if (map[playerPos[0]][playerPos[1] - 1] == '█')
                    {
                        // Nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        playerPos[1]--;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    NextRoom1();

                    char[] chars = mapNow.ToCharArray();
                    chars[1] = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(chars[1]) + 1);
                    mapNow = new string(chars);

                    playerPos[1] = 14;
                    _playerPosTEMP[1] = 14;
                    playerPos[0] = 4;
                    _playerPosTEMP[0] = 4;

                    NextRoom2();
                }
            }
            if (key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
            {
                if (!IsExit(key))
                {
                    if (map[playerPos[0]][playerPos[1] + 1] == '█')
                    {
                        // Nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        playerPos[1]++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    NextRoom1();

                    char[] chars = mapNow.ToCharArray();
                    chars[1] = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(chars[1]) - 1);
                    mapNow = new string(chars);

                    playerPos[1] = 0;
                    _playerPosTEMP[1] = 0;
                    playerPos[0] = 4;
                    _playerPosTEMP[0] = 4;

                    NextRoom2();
                }
            }
        }










        static bool IsExit(ConsoleKey key)
        {
            if (key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow && playerPos[0] - 1 < 0 ||
                key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow && playerPos[0] + 1 > 8 ||
                key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow && playerPos[1] - 1 < 0 ||
                key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow && playerPos[1] + 1 > 14)
            {
            
                return true;
            }

            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }







        static void NextRoom1()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
            ShowMap(mapNow);

            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            ShowMap(mapNow);
        }

        static void NextRoom2()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
            ShowMap(mapNow);

            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            ShowMap(mapNow);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of your `NextRoomX()` methods, call `ClearBuffer()`:

```
static void ClearBuffer()
{
    while (Console.KeyAvailable) {
        Console.ReadKey(false);
    }            
}
```

Comment: Omg! Thank you very much! I've suffered over this for so long! This really works!